# Can someone please guide me about twilio sms and voice integration with Dialogflow cx?

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat, dialogflow-cx

i'm searching for guideness about twilio voice and sms and the integration of these with dialogflow cx, i'm just learning about it and I think the information and documentation I've found is not enough and it's kind of confusiong to me.

I've already have a Twilio number connected to a webhook which I created from GCP run and build, but I don't know if I'm ignoring an important step, i'd be very grateful if someone can help me.

I've researching and found a repository where they explain the integration with twilio but focusing in whatsapp, this is my code:

```
imports...

const sessionClient = new SessionsClient({
  apiEndpoint: `${process.env.LOCATION}-dialogflow.googleapis.com`,
});

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const listener = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8081, () => {
  console.log('Your Dialogflow integration server is listening on port ' +
  listener.address().port);
});

const twilioToDetectIntent = (twilioReq) => {
    const sessionId = twilioReq.body.To;
    const sessionPath = sessionClient.projectLocationAgentSessionPath (
        process.env.PROJECT_ID,
        process.env.LOCATION,
        process.env.AGENT_ID,
        sessionId
    );

    const message = twilioReq.body.Body;
    const languageCode = process.env.LANGUAGE_CODE;
    const request = {
        session: sessionPath,
        queryInput:
            {
                text: {
                    text: message
                },
                languageCode
            }
        };
    
    return request;
};

const detectIntentToTwilio = (dialogflowResponse) => {
  let reply = "";
  
  for (let responseMessage of dialogflowResponse.queryResult.responseMessages) {
      if (responseMessage.hasOwnProperty('text')) {
          reply += responseMessage.text.text;
      }
  }

  const twiml = new  MessagingResponse();
  twiml.message(reply);
  return twiml;
};

const getResponseMessage = async (req) => {
  const dialogflowRequest = twilioToDetectIntent(req);
  const [dialogflowResponse] = await sessionClient.detectIntent(dialogflowRequest);
  const twiml = detectIntentToTwilio(dialogflowResponse);
  return twiml.toString();
};

//voice
const sendToDialogflowVoice = async (speechResult, callSid) => {
  const sessionPath = sessionClient.projectLocationAgentSessionPath(
    process.env.PROJECT_ID,
    process.env.LOCATION,
    process.env.AGENT_ID,
    callSid
  );

  const request = {
    session: sessionPath,
    queryInput: {
      audio: {
        config: {
          languageCode: process.env.LANGUAGE_CODE,
        },
        audio: speechResult, // El mensaje de voz
      },
    },
  };

  try {
    const [response] = await sessionClient.detectIntent(request);
    const messageFromDialogflow = response.queryResult.responseMessages[0].text.text;
    return messageFromDialogflow;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Something ocurred', error);
    return 'error from Dialogflow.';
  }
};

app.post('/sms', async (req, res) => {
  const message = await getResponseMessage(req);
    console.log("MESSAGE: " + message);
    res.send(message);
});

app.post('/voice', async (req, res) => {
  const speechResult = req.body.SpeechResult;
  const callSid = req.body.CallSid;
  const dialogflowResponse = await sendToDialogflowVoice(speechResult, callSid);

  const twiml = new MessagingResponse();
  twiml.message(dialogflowResponse);

  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
  res.send(twiml.toString());
});

process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
  listener.close(async ()=> {
    console.log('Closing server.');
    process.exit(0);
  });
});

exports...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate with Voice using One click Integration but would have to add this "virtualagent-ccai-prod@dialogflow-prod-env.iam.gserviceaccount.com" in your project via IAM.

[Link to One Click Integration of Voice Agent with Twilio:](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/virtual-agent/dialogflow-cx-onboarding)

For Integrating with SMS you would have to build via Twilio Studio.

Step#1: Create Session for incoming First Message.

Step#2: Pass the Session and First incoming Message to Dialogflow API.

Step#3: Send the Dialogflow API response via Send and Wait Widget to wait for user response this will work in a loop. You will also to add a way to handle end session and so on.

Just Import this into Twilio Studio adjust according to your Needs. Let me know if further help is needed : )

```
    {
  "description": "Dialogflow CX Sample",
  "states": [
    {
      "name": "Trigger",
      "type": "trigger",
      "transitions": [
        {
          "next": "SetUtteranceVariable",
          "event": "incomingMessage"
        },
        {
          "event": "incomingCall"
        },
        {
          "event": "incomingConversationMessage"
        },
        {
          "event": "incomingRequest"
        },
        {
          "event": "incomingParent"
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "offset": {
          "x": -70,
          "y": -860
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "SetUtteranceVariable",
      "type": "set-variables",
      "transitions": [
        {
          "next": "http_get_session",
          "event": "next"
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "variables": [
          {
            "value": "{{trigger.message.Body}}",
            "key": "utterance"
          },
          {
            "value": "{{trigger.message.From}}",
            "key": "From"
          },
          {
            "value": "{{trigger.call.To}}",
            "key": "To"
          }
        ],
        "offset": {
          "x": -30,
          "y": -620
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "ResetUtteranceVariable",
      "type": "set-variables",
      "transitions": [
        {
          "next": "Dialogflow",
          "event": "next"
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "variables": [
          {
            "value": "{{widgets.SendDialogflowAnswerAndWaitForReply.inbound.Body}}",
            "key": "utterance"
          }
        ],
        "offset": {
          "x": 110,
          "y": -200
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "send_message_virtual_agent_error",
      "type": "send-message",
      "transitions": [
        {
          "event": "sent"
        },
        {
          "event": "failed"
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "offset": {
          "x": 1430,
          "y": 240
        },
        "service": "{{trigger.message.InstanceSid}}",
        "channel": "{{trigger.message.ChannelSid}}",
        "from": "{{flow.channel.address}}",
        "to": "{{contact.channel.address}}",
        "body": "Sorry, couldn't connect to our backend systems. Call us at {{trigger.call.To}}  or visit our website at Dynamic Value."
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "http_get_session",
      "type": "make-http-request",
      "transitions": [
        {
          "next": "Dialogflow",
          "event": "success"
        },
        {
          "next": "send_message_session_error",
          "event": "failed"
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "offset": {
          "x": 890,
          "y": -560
        },
        "method": "POST",
        "content_type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        "body": "{\"from\":\"{{trigger.message.From}}\",\"to\":\"{{trigger.message.To}}\",\"fulfillmentInfo\":\"Twilio\"}",
        "url": "https://us-east1-airia-voximplant.cloudfunctions.net/get-session"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "send_message_session_error",
      "type": "send-message",
      "transitions": [
        {
          "event": "sent"
        },
        {
          "event": "failed"
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "offset": {
          "x": 1490,
          "y": -250
        },
        "service": "{{trigger.message.InstanceSid}}",
        "channel": "{{trigger.message.ChannelSid}}",
        "from": "{{flow.channel.address}}",
        "to": "{{contact.channel.address}}",
        "body": "Sorry, we are not able to create a session for you on the call. please send a message to {{trigger.call.To}}  or reach our website dynamic value."
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Dialogflow",
      "type": "make-http-request",
      "transitions": [
        {
          "next": "SendDialogflowAnswerAndWaitForReply",
          "event": "success"
        },
        {
          "next": "send_message_virtual_agent_error",
          "event": "failed"
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "offset": {
          "x": 840,
          "y": -220
        },
        "method": "POST",
        "content_type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        "body": "{\"utterance\":\"{{flow.variables.utterance}}\",\"caller_session\":\"{{widgets.http_get_session.parsed.caller_session}}\",\"caller_id\":\"{{widgets.http_get_session.parsed.caller_id}}\",\"called_number\":\"{{widgets.http_get_session.parsed.called_number}}\",\"phonenumber_type\":\"{{widgets.http_get_session.parsed.phonenumber_type}}\"}",
        "url": "https://us-east1-airia-voximplant.cloudfunctions.net/cx-api"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "SendDialogflowAnswerAndWaitForReply",
      "type": "send-and-wait-for-reply",
      "transitions": [
        {
          "next": "ResetUtteranceVariable",
          "event": "incomingMessage"
        },
        {
          "event": "timeout"
        },
        {
          "event": "deliveryFailure"
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "offset": {
          "x": 800,
          "y": 220
        },
        "service": "{{trigger.message.InstanceSid}}",
        "channel": "{{trigger.message.ChannelSid}}",
        "from": "{{flow.channel.address}}",
        "body": "{{widgets.Dialogflow.parsed. \nresponse_message}}",
        "timeout": "3600"
      }
    }
  ],
  "initial_state": "Trigger",
  "flags": {
    "allow_concurrent_calls": true
  }
}
```